# Background effect in CSS

Tags: html, css

I found this site: https://jonasreymondin.com/ (It isn't mine, It just random site I found)

In the background there is a strange effect, I have no idea what it's called or how to do it, does anyone know anything?

I am talking about dot/glitch effect (you have to be careful to notice it), not the parallax effect.

I found this line of code, by deleting this line the effect disappears:

`<canvas class="grain" width="976" height="927"></canvas>`

I search in the code what that tag do but I don't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this js pen [here](https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/PwyoMm), it meight help

```
 <div id="container">
    <style>
    #canvas {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
     <div id="image"></div>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a canvas code, if it is an external plugin you may need to install it or else you need to copy the code.

[Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134714/view-canvas-element-source-code/11135350)